# I have a dag that runs with a dynamic task group that fails when the number of dynamic tasks changes

Tags: dynamic, airflow, task

I have a dag the runs either 8 tasks or 16 tasks (or doing testing, any multiple pairs up to 8 pairs).
When the task group ends, the next task evaluates the results of the prior tasks.
But this fails for unknown reasons when the prior run (which is successful) has a different count of tasks.
When there are less tasks than the prior, ghosts tasks appear in the task group as failures (they were not generated or wanted) or when there are more tasks the evaluation task fails as not all dependencies are met.
So it looks like these dependencies are held over from the prior task.
If I was to trigger the dag again, it runs normally but when the count of dynamic tasks changes, it will error again.
What can I do to resolve this?
[Here is a graph of a failure after the number of tasks is increased from 2 to 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faqIP.png)
The is no log for the error task but the task instance details has this:
Dependency  Reason
Dagrun Running  Task instance's dagrun was not in the 'running' state but in the state 'failed'.
Task Instance State     Task is in the 'failed' state.
Don't know how it got into a "failed" state.
[Here is a graph with ghost tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7jhp.png)
This particular run was successful regardless of the ghost tasks, must of been my tweak of: trigger_rule="all_done",
But I still don't want to see images of tasks that should not be there.
Let me know what you all think.

Mark

I have changed the task after the first task group to trigger on all_done, that seemed to work.
But still have issues when the number of tasks increase, and still have ghosts tasks that should not be in the graph.

> #Here is how first group is generated:
> with TaskGroup("group_hadr_status") as group_hadr_status:
> context = {}
> conn = db2connectionhook(database_conn_id="DB_DB2_DBA_DB",**context)
> servers_to_process = conn.execute("select server from patchTuesday.servers order by 1")
> del conn
> ROW_COUNT=0
> for server in servers_to_process:
> ROW_COUNT+=1
> server = server[0]
> logging.info("group_hadr_status server = %s", server)
> making dynamic task: "get_hadr_status_" + server in group get_hadr_status
> get_hadr_status_task=PythonOperator(
> task_id='get_hadr_status_' + server,
> dag=patchTuesday,
> execution_timeout = timedelta(seconds=300),  #300 -> 5 minutes
> python_callable=get_hadr_status,
> retries= 0,
> op_args=[server],
> )
> MAX_SWIM_LANES = ROW_COUNT/2
> init_patch_tuesday_task.set_downstream(group_hadr_status)
>
> #Here is how I define the orchestration_task task:
> patch_orchestration_task = PythonOperator(
> task_id='patch_orchestration_id',
> dag=patchTuesday,
> python_callable=patch_orchestration,
> provide_context=True,
> trigger_rule="all_done",
> on_failure_callback=notify_email,
> op_args=[])
> group_hadr_status.set_downstream(patch_orchestration_task)
> `

Comment: can you please wrap your code in three backticks (\```) to render the code in a readable format? Also, adding "python" after the first set of backticks allows it to be rendered as Python, e.g. \```python

Comment: [More info on code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dynamic task mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html). Airflow's dynamic task mapping allows for the definition of a variable number of tasks that aren't known until the DAG actually runs. I quite like the TaskFlow API (e.g. using `@task`), but you can also [map over "classic" Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-over-result-of-classic-operators) such as the `PythonOperator` in your example.